# Assign a input value to variable on same page with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with a api where i need to post a url from a form and get response. Everything is working well except one thing. I could not figure out how to get url posted in form input in to a variable for javascript. Take a look at following.

```
 <form action="#" method="post">
 <input type="text" class="url" name="url" />
 <input type="submit" value="Analyse for Page Speed" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

I use above form to get url and i want that url to be a value for the following variable

```
 // Specify the URL you want PageSpeed results for here:
 var URL_TO_GET_RESULTS_FOR = 'your url here';
```

How to get this done?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this. Your title is misleading.

Comment: You should give the form an ID so that you can select it with Javascript.

Comment: You want to set that variable value with the field `url` value? Or the reverse? And **when** you want that. In which event?

Comment: @crush: This can be done with jQuery. What's wrong with the OP asking for a jQuery solution?

Comment: @Travesty3 A) He didn't tag it as jQuery. B) He didn't mention jQuery anywhere in his question. C) Using jQuery simply for this would be extreme overkill/misuse of a third party library if he isn't already using it for other things.

Comment: @crush: I think we can assume he is using it already since he asked for a jQuery solution (in the title). Regardless of where he put it, it's pretty clear what he wants. This is different than someone suggesting to start using jQuery for a trivial problem such as this. Not all newbies are good at choosing all of the appropriate tags for their question.

Comment: @Travesty3 How do you know that he didn't confuse the terms? Nowhere is there any indication in the body or tags of the question that he is using or wants to use jQuery. Only does jQuery exist in the title. That's all I meant by it's "misleading". Does he want jQuery or Javascript? ***I don't know***.

Comment: @crush: I'm pretty convinced that jQuery is already available. If you're not sure about it, perhaps it would be better to simply ask that question. Your comment gives off a vibe of telling him that he's doing something wrong.

Comment: @Travesty3 I'm not going to argue with you about it. From my perspective, it was very unclear. Period.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var URL_TO_GET_RESULTS_FOR = document.getElementsByName('url')[0].value;
```

`getElementsByName` returns an array with all elements having the name passed as parameter. Since I'm assuming you have only one element with `name="url"`, I get the first position of the array and returns the value.

Comment: I believe he wants that too, but he doesn't especified *when*.

Answer (score 1):

As @crush pointed out in the comments, this task alone probably does not merit the use of jQuery. So if you aren't already using it, this should probably not be the deciding factor. If you need a pure JS solution, go with @ClaudioRedi's answer.

However, I'm assuming you're already using jQuery, and are asking for a jQuery solution. So here it is:

```
var URL_TO_GET_RESULTS_FOR = $('form input[name="url"]').val();
```

This will get the value of an `<input>` with the name `url` within a `<form>` element.